# How do I get the id for a media file given it's path?

Tags: orchardcms

I've tried looking through the source and can see no examples of this.

I need to assign a media file's id to a field (`MediaLibraryPickerField`), I have the media file's path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inject `IMediaLibraryService`, then query using `GetMediaContenItems()`. This gives you a query object that you can add a where clause to. You can add a `Where` clause that restricts on the `FolderPath` and `FileName`.